# How to stop Windows Alarms (Clock) app from asking access permissions on startup without saying yes or signing in?

Tags: windows, alarm-clock

Sometime this year, the Windows Clock App that comes with Windows 10/11 asks for permissions every time on startup:

> Let this app access your info? Windows Alarms needs your
> permission to: Read your profile  Create, read, update and delete your
> tasks and plans  Accepting these permissions means that you allow this
> app to use your data as specified in their Terms of Service and
> Privacy Statement. The publisher has not provided links to their terms
> for you to review. You can change these permissions at
> https://microsoft.com/consent.

I always click "No" and don't want to sign in either. Is there another way to stop it from asking every time it starts? Would appreciate a simple solution.

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling, same thing.

**Update (May 2023)**: It's been over a month since I've seen this. My guess is that some Windows update fixed it, intentionally or not. Won't be able to test or verify any other solutions.

Comment: Not here on any Windows 10 / 11 machine.  Run DISM / SFC and test .......   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Thanks, need some time to research and understand that before I try it.

Comment: DISM and SFC is not at all risky to run .  SFC may take some time if much to repair